# OnTouchListener in View that is inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, ontouchlistener

I have a View that is inside `ScrollView`. I want to call some method every 80ms as long as the user is holding that View pressed. This is what i have implemented:

```
final Runnable vibrate = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        vibrate();
    }
};

theView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            final ScheduledFuture<?> vibrateHandle =
                    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(vibrate, 0, 80, MILLISECONDS);
            vibrateHanlers.add(vibrateHandle);
            return true;
        }
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
                || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            clearAllScheduledFutures();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

The problem is, `ACTION_CANCEL` is called for the smallest move of the finger. I know that is because the `View` is inside `ScrollView`, but i am not sure what are my options here. Do i create custom `ScrollView`, and try to find if the desired View is touched and disable the touch event for the `ScrollView`? Or maybe, disable the touch event for `SrollView` for small threshold of moving? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is how i fixed it.

I created custom `ScrollView`:

```
public class MainScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private boolean shouldStopInterceptingTouchEvent = false;

    public void setShouldStopInterceptingTouchEvent(boolean shouldStopInterceptingTouchEvent) {
        this.shouldStopInterceptingTouchEvent = shouldStopInterceptingTouchEvent;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (shouldStopInterceptingTouchEvent)
            return false;
        else
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

And in the onTouchEvent:

```
theView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            svMain.setShouldStopInterceptingTouchEvent(true);
            final ScheduledFuture<?> vibrateHandle =
                    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(vibrate, 0, 80, MILLISECONDS);
            vibrateHanlers.add(vibrateHandle);
            return true;
        }
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
                || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            svMain.setShouldStopInterceptingTouchEvent(false);
            clearAllScheduledFutures();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

So, instead of determining when to stop intercepting `touchEvent` in the `ScrollView`, i am deciding that in the `onTouchListener` of the `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to return true instead of false in ActionUp event such that event considered consumed

```
if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
                || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            clearAllScheduledFutures();
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what am i returning there, because the `ACTION_CANCEL` is called and i am stopping the `Runnable` from executing the `vibrate()` method. The problem is that `ACTION_CANCEL` is called prematurely. And if i remove the  `ACTION_CANCEL` check, then `ACTION_UP` is never called and i am not able to stop the `Runnable`.

Comment: I think you may need to user onInterceptTouchEvent.

If you return true from here, you will not receive any following events: the target view will receive the same event but with the action MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, and all further events will be delivered to your onTouchEvent() method and no longer appear here.

check this : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29

Comment: Yes, i have to experiment with custom ScrollView and onInterceptTouchEvent method.

Comment: if it works well, we need to update the answer such that others can get benefit.
Thanks!